# Running JSF in stateless mode (0 costs for state saving)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, myfaces, jsf-stateless

I recently came across a [stateless extension for JSF](http://industrieit.com/blog/2011/11/stateless-jsf-high-performance-zero-per-request-memory-overhead/)(Mojarra) developed by Rudi which claims to deliver vast improvements in performance at even lower costs of memory/ CPU & reduced latency, with 0 memory overhead for state saving & also saying goodbye to stale views(Postbacks will always work). All this seems much much impressive!

I'm a naive JSF developer involved in projects using JSF for high performance internet application.
I wanted to know what concerns should I be worried about before migrating to stateless pages in JSF. I have already tested my app with this stateless project(most of the things work seamlessly except some) but I wanted to know the things I should be thinking of before migrating.

I know there is already a [proposal](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1055) to include the Stateless mode feature in the official JSF specs as well but I'm not sure how long that would take to happen, & till the time this JSF extension could be of great help to me.

Also, is there any one out there, also using Stateless JSF project in production environments ?

--

**Update:**
For those working with Myfaces the stateless extension has been reimplemented by Thomas Andraschko & has been [proposed to be added to Myfaces core project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-3465).

---

Using JSF 2.1.3 with Stateless Extension & Primefaces 3.4 Snapshot.

Comment: I have been testing my project against this while development & also I'm planning to use in production..

Comment: If *"is there any one out there, also using Stateless JSF project in production environments?"* is all what your concrete question covers, then I'm sorry to say that you're here on Stack Overflow at the [wrong place](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). SO is as being a Q&A site not a platform for discussion or lists/collections. Look for a discussion forum.